# Best way to view white SVG on Windows

Tags: microsoft-edge, svg, viewer

SVG can be readily viewed in Edge browser. However white SVG on white browser background aren't good to see. Do I need to install an external program for this or am I missing a setting?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy to use native Windows tools or Edge with different settings. If that's possible. "Use a different program" would be good enough as an answer. I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct way to view white SVGs but you can do some hack to view them on a chrome browser. Drag and drop the svg to chrome browser and open the dev tools(f12 or ctrl + shift + i) and change the background color of the topmost DOM element to black and voila you can view the white SVG.

[Find the topmost dom and change the background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHDg6.png)

[white svg on black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KT0r.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a bookmarklet to set the background to a checkerboard pattern.
Create a bookmark and set this as the URL

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.style.background = null;document.body.children[0].style.background=null; document.children[0].style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill-opacity="0.3" width="50" height="50" ><g fill="grey"><rect x="50" width="50" height="50" /><rect y="50" width="50" height="50" /></g><rect width="50" height="50" /><rect y="50" x="50" width="50" height="50" /></svg>')`;})();
```

Then if you load a SVG that is white hit this bookmark and it will set the background to a checkerboard.

I keep improving that bookmarklet so the repo is here: https://github.com/Myster/TransparentBackgroundRevealer
It also includes a hotlink to the latest version. So you may wish to fork so you can review any changes.

Comment: Pasting it into the Chrome/Edge Console I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`, but the GitHub version works OK.